# Alpha Images convert to .mov

Tags: ios, uiimage, mov, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I have been able to create the playing .mov, by following the various [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) on stack.

However, my image contains alpha.

```
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             bitmapInfo);
```

This produces

[image]

I have a feeling, its due to the `bitmapInfo`, but when I use `kCGImageAlphaLast` my app crashes with

This error

**CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 688 bytes/row.**

I'm hoping there is an easy solution, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my full pixelBufferCode

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image {

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight);

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          size.width,
                                          size.height,
                                          kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                          (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    if (status != kCVReturnSuccess){
        NSLog(@"Failed to create pixel buffer");
    }

    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);


    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaLast;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                                 size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 bitmapInfo);
    //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

Comment: Problem was images need to be a factor of 16 ! Go figure :-)

Comment: The size of the bytes per row can change. Where you have **4*size.width** you should replace that with **CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer)**.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964695/ios-5-uiview-converted-to-video-and-the-resulting-video-is-corrupted) for full details.